# How can I find & groups pairs from an array while changing the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

So for ex. I have this array with these values :

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4];
```

How can I get a new arr as :

```
let newArr = [3, 3, 4, 4];
```

while at the same time the original array should be changed as :

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

one 3 is left behind cause there is only one pair of 3.

I tried this code below ( a for loop & splice ) but it is not working properly.

```
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    if (sorted[i] === sorted[i + 1]) {
        let pair = sorted.splice(i, 1);
        pair.forEach(el => result.push(el));
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re mutating the array while iterating without adjusting the index. `console.log({ i, sorted: sorted.slice(), current: sorted[i] });` would help with debugging. `--i;` decrements a number by one.

Comment: @RameshReddy The array name `sorted` implies it.

Comment: I wanted to ask if he's sorting the array or if the input is already sorted.

Comment: i am sorting the array.

Comment: How can I adjust the index after finding a pair ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things corrected,

1. You need to `splice` two items from the point you see duplicates.
   Try like this.
2. Iteration stop condition should be `i < sorted.length - 1` as we consider two consecutive items.
3. Use [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to join duplicates to the result array.

```js
let sorted = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4];
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted[i] === sorted[i + 1]) {
        let pair = sorted.splice(i, 2);
        result = result.concat(pair);
        i--;
    }
}

console.log(sorted)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Arya, check this out !!

Comment: thanks man. Ya, I was splicing 2 items. Splicing 1 was a typo. But why should the stopping condition be length - 1 ?

Comment: Because last item has no another item to compare with. But the code works fine as it returns undefined instead of throwing a runtime error

Comment: Right it does work fine. Thanks for your time Amila, I'll use the condition just as a good practice 

Comment: Are you suggesting I should not decrement ??

Comment: @Rabten, you need to shift back once(i--) a duplicate is found as we are changing the array using splice. Because there could be a pair we missing. Updated the answer!